# How to pass exception futher from Websphere's startWork task?

Tags: java, multithreading, websphere, runnable

I've got my own class that implements `com.ibm.websphere.asynchbeans.Work` with the following run method:

```
@Override
public void run() {
  try {
    agentManager.loadLibContent(agent);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    ErrorAnalizer.report(e);
    log.error("some err: "+e.getMessage());
    //this.setStatus("error");
    //throw new RuntimeException(e);
  } finally {
    workLoadManager.delRunTask(getTaskHistory());
  }
}
```

This work-class is passed to startWork(Work var1) method of `com.ibm.websphere.asynchbeans.WorkManager`.

When I get an exception in the try block it is being caught and logged, no problem.

**But** I want that exception to go upper till it reaches the very first method that called websphere's startWork.

**How to do that?** `Runnable` does not let to throw checked exception. `RuntimeException` didn't help. It seems startWork swallows it somewhere inside.

Bad thing that this first method is located in another project module and I can not reach it from catch block to pass info to do some job.

I also tried to setStatus in my work-class and then get it after but looks like startWork don't let me to change passed object.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [WorkItem.getResult](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/asynchbeans/WorkItem.html) method:

```
MyWork myWork = ...
WorkItem wi = wm.startWork(myWork);
...
try {
    myWork = (MyWork)wi.getResult();
    ...
} catch (WorkException e) {
    Throwable cause = e.getCause();
    ...
}
```

Then, there are two options:

1. The catch block in your `run` method can store the exception in an instance field, and then you can retrieve it after calling getResult.
2. The `run` method throws an unchecked exception, and it should be available as the cause of the `WorkException` that is caught.

Answer (score 1):

To get the result of submitted asynchbeans `Work`, you can store a reference to the `com.ibm.websphere.asynchbeans.WorkItem` and invoke `getResult()` which will return the result of your work if it completed successfully, or it will throw a `com.ibm.websphere.asynchbeans.WorkException` which wraps the exception thrown by the `Work` implementation.

Here is an example:

```
// Submit the work
WorkItem workItem = workManager.startWork(new MyWork());

// Wait for the work to be done for up to 60s
ArrayList<WorkItem> items = new ArrayList<WorkItem>();
boolean workFinished = workManager.join(items, WorkManager.JOIN_AND, 60*1000);

if(workFinished)
  try {
    MyWork work = workItem.getResult();
    // if we get here, the work completed without errors
  } catch(WorkException e) {
    throw e.getCause(); // this will be the exception thrown by your Work impl
  } 
else {
  // the Work did not finish in 60s
}
```